# How do I set namespace attributes on an XElement

Tags: .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I need to add the following attributes to an XElement:

```xml
<xmlns="http://www.mysite.com/myresource" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mysite.com/myresource TheResource.xsd">
```

Adding them as an XAttribute doesn't work because of the ":" and I'm sure is not the right way anyways. How do I add these on there?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It took scouring [a lot of blogs](http://www.falconwebtech.com/post/2010/06/03/Adding-schemaLocation-attribute-to-XElement-in-LINQ-to-XML.aspx) but I finally came up with what I think is the "right" way to do this:

```cs
XNamespace ns = @"http://www.myapp.com/resource";
XNamespace xsi = @"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

var root = new XElement(ns + "root", 
  new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns+"xsi", xsi.NamespaceName),
  new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", @"http://www.myapp/resource TheResource.xsd")
);
```

Answer (score 12):

I think what you want is described here: [How to: Create a Document with Namespaces (C#) (LINQ to XML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387075.aspx)

To take an example from it:

```cs
// Create an XML tree in a namespace.
XNamespace aw = "http://www.adventure-works.com";
XElement root = new XElement(aw + "Root",
    new XElement(aw + "Child", "child content")
);
Console.WriteLine(root);
```

would produce:

```
<Root xmlns="http://www.adventure-works.com">
  <Child>child content</Child>
</Root>
```

Comment: This is only part of the question. See my answer below for how I ended up doing it.