# DataContractSerializer to deserialize a Member without namespace?

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, datacontractserializer, datamember

I need to deserialize this xml (that I can't change):

```
<foo:a xmlns:foo="http://example.com">
  <b>string</b>
</foo:a>
```

I made this class:

```
[DataContract(Name = "a", Namespace = "http://example.com")]
public class A
{
    [DataMember(Name = "b", Order = 0)]
    public string B;
}
```

And I did:

```
using (var streamObject = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)))
{
    var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(A));
    return (A)ser.ReadObject(streamObject);
}
```

I get an object of class A, but the content of B is always null. I know it would work if the xml was using `<foo:b>string</foo:b>`, but that is not the case. What can I do to deserialize a DataMember with no namespace?

Comment: Good one. Do you have to use DataContract serialization?

Comment: you can remove namespace at all `Namespace = ""` in your datacontract attribute. then you'll end up having <a> and <b>

Comment: @Andrew, than the xml won't deserialize

Comment: sorry, I thought he uses this class to create the xml as well

Comment: @d_z no, I don't have to... but it would save me some trouble (like: I did everything else for the app, including soap and json, with DataContractSerializer). I would dislike to mix the handling of this and json differently.

Comment: @Cœur, Got it. I asked because XmlSerializer has this capability and DataContractSerializer doesn't

Answer (score 2):

if you can do the pre-processing of xml before deserializing it, then try to do the following:

make namespace in your datacontract empty:

```
[DataContract(Name = "a", Namespace = "")]
public class A
{
    [DataMember(Name = "b", Order = 0)]
    public string B;
}
```

remove the namespace attribute from your xml before deserializing it

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("your xml here");
XElement root = doc.Root;

XAttribute attr = root.Attribute("xmlns");
if (attr != null) 
{
    attr.Remove();
}
```

and then deserialize the updated xml:

```
string newXml = doc.ToString();   

A result = null;
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(A));

using (StringReader backing = new StringReader(newXml))
{
    using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(backing))
    {
        result = (A) serializer.ReadObject(reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, removing namespace altogether was my current workaround. I was using a Regexp.Replace(); I'll see if I can use XAttribute.Remove() as you suggest. But some issue with this solution is that I also need to hack the serialization to insert the namespace later on.

Comment: why an XmlTextReader instead of a MemoryStream? Any link to why it would be better?

Comment: to add namespace back, please have a look at the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021931/how-do-i-set-namespace-attributes-on-an-xelement or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387075.aspx. You can use MemoryStream, I'm just used to work with XmlTextReader.