# Using XML to Linq to Iterate an ICollection

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a collection of objects that I need to iterate over and pull data out to create an XML file.  I am trying to use XML Linq to do so, but it appears I am not grasping the concept.  Here is my code:

```
 string jSonProducts = File.ReadAllText(settings.productJsonConfig.JSONProductFilePath);

        ICollection<ProductSearchModel> prods = null;
        prods = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ICollection<ProductSearchModel>>(jSonProducts);

        foreach (ProductSearchModel prod in prods)
        {
            var xmlNode =
            new XElement("Feed",
                new XAttribute("xmlns", settings.bvXMLConfig.xmlns),
                new XAttribute("name", settings.bvXMLConfig.xmlName),
                new XAttribute("incrmental", settings.bvXMLConfig.xmlIncremental),
                new XAttribute("extractDate",DateTime.UtcNow),
                new XElement("Products"),
                 new XElement("Product"),
                    new XElement("ExternalId", prod.SKU),
                    new XElement("Name", prod.Description.Name),
                    new XElement("Description", prod.Description.Description),
                    new XElement("BrandExternalID",prod.Properties.Brand.FeedName),
                    new XElement("CategoryExternalId"), //look up the category here by sku
                    new XElement("ModelNumbers"),
                        new XElement("ModelNumber",prod.SKU),
                    new XElement("ManufacturingPartNumbers"),
                        new XElement("ManufacturingPartNumber",prod.SKU),
                    new XElement("UPCs"),
                        new XElement("UPC", prod.UPC),
                    new XElement("Attributes"),
                    new XElement("Attribute"),
                        new XAttribute("id","BV_FE_FAMILY"),
                        new XElement("Value")
                );

        }
```

I am trying to create the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Feed xmlns="http://www.bazaarvoice.com/xs/PRR/ProductFeed/14.7" name="LifetimeProducts" incremental="false" extractDate="2017-10-20T13:21:41">

   <Products>
        <Product>
            <ExternalId>12345</ExternalId>
            <Name>Product 1</Name>
                                <Description>
                <![CDATA[Proudct Description]]></Description>
            <BrandExternalId>Brandx</BrandExternalId>
            <CategoryExternalId>Category</CategoryExternalId>
                                <ProductPageUrl><![CDATA[http://something.com]]></ProductPageUrl>
                <ImageUrl>http://image.com</ImageUrl>
            <ModelNumbers>
                <ModelNumber>12345</ModelNumber>
            </ModelNumbers>
            <ManufacturerPartNumbers>
                <ManufacturerPartNumber>12345</ManufacturerPartNumber>
            </ManufacturerPartNumbers>
            <Attributes>
                <Attribute id="BV_FE_FAMILY">
                    <Value>Family</Value>
                </Attribute>
                                    <Attribute id="BV_FE_FAMILY">
                    <Value>Family2</Value>
                </Attribute>
                                    <Attribute id="BV_FE_FAMILY">
                    <Value>Family 3</Value>
                </Attribute>
            </Attributes>
        </Product>
     </Products>
```

I need only one feed node (as the root) and then have the products nodes under this one. This doesn't seem to be working and this is my first time really working with LINQ and XML.  The code appears to be pulling the data into the nodes, but with the foreach loop I think I am doing this wrong.  What do I need to tweak to get this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just for clarification, prod contains a lot more data than needed to create this XML, so to just serialize prod will work.  I need to push the prod data into these sets of XML tags.

Comment: In c#, indenting isn't significant. You don't pass a parameter by indenting it relative to the method call you want to pass it to. You pass it by putting it inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you pass arguments to methods by putting them inside the parentheses. For example, this won't work:

```
double sqrt = Math.Sqrt(),
                  1234;
```

You do it like this:

```
double sqrt = Math.Sqrt(1234);
```

You're also trying to create a new root node all over again for every item in the collection. Instead, you want *one* root node, which contains multiple children.

So your code should probably look something like this. Bear in mind that I don't have your settings or your `ProductSearchModel` class, so I haven't tested this. I'm relying on the assumption that your indentation, at least, reflects your intent, and the names of the elements (ModelNumbers/ModelNumber etc.) seem to bear that out.

The guts of the loop look similar to your code at first glance, but pay close attention to the parentheses. They make all the difference in the world.

```
var xFeed = 
    new XElement("Feed",
        new XAttribute("xmlns", settings.bvXMLConfig.xmlns),
        new XAttribute("name", settings.bvXMLConfig.xmlName),
        new XAttribute("incrmental", settings.bvXMLConfig.xmlIncremental),
        new XAttribute("extractDate", DateTime.UtcNow)
    );

var xProducts = new XElement("Products");
xFeed.Add(xProducts);

foreach (ProductSearchModel prod in prods)
{
    var xProduct = 
        new XElement("Product",
            new XElement("ExternalId", prod.SKU),
            new XElement("Name", prod.Description.Name),
            new XElement("Description", prod.Description.Description),
            new XElement("BrandExternalID", prod.Properties.Brand.FeedName),
            new XElement("CategoryExternalId"), //look up the category here by sku
            new XElement("ModelNumbers",
                new XElement("ModelNumber", prod.SKU)),
            new XElement("ManufacturingPartNumbers",
                new XElement("ManufacturingPartNumber", prod.SKU)),
            new XElement("UPCs",
                new XElement("UPC", prod.UPC)),
            new XElement("Attributes"),
            new XElement("Attribute",
                new XAttribute("id", "BV_FE_FAMILY"),
                new XElement("Value"))
        );
    xProducts.Add(xProduct);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great starting point for me.  I was working through the parenthesis based on the comment above.

Comment: When I try to save this file using xFeed.Save([path]) I get this error:

{"The prefix '' cannot be redefined from '' to 'http://www.bazaarvoice.com/xs/PRR/ProductFeed/14.7' within the same start element tag."}

Comment: @john You may need to give it an XNamespace like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11023060/424129